# Concatenating Text and Hyperlink in same Table Cell C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, hyperlink

At the moment I have two table cells in the same row.

1st Cell's text: "If you need help...contact"

2nd Cell's text: Help Link

So that it displays as:

"If you need help...contact___________________`Help Link`

I need to get it down to only one cell so that I can remove the white space between the text and the help link.

I tried to just add one cell and concatenate like:

```
cell1.Text = "If you need help...contact "+myPlaceHolder;
```

which didn't throw an error but only showed the c# code.

Anyways, here is my code:

```
               TableCell cell2= new TableCell();
                cell2.Width = Unit.Percentage(25);
                TableCell cell1 = new TableCell();
                cell1.Width = Unit.Percentage(75);

                HyperLink myHyperLink= new HyperLink();
                myHyperLink.Text = "Help Link";
                myHyperLink.NavigateUrl = String.Format("javascript:void(window.open('" + myURL + "','_blank'));");

                PlaceHolder myPlaceHolder= new PlaceHolder();

                myPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(myHyperLink);


                cell2.Controls.Add(myPlaceHolder);

                cell1.Text = "If you need help...contact";

                rowEmp_Relations.Cells.Add(cell1);
                rowEmp_Relations.Cells.Add(cell2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you use a place holder here.  Just use a literal control, it will display the markup correctly (supposed to).  The click doesn't work on this code yet, but if you tweak it I'm sure you can figure it out.  It does solve your primary question about displaying the text together.

```
   Literal lit = new Literal();
   string myURL = "http://www.google.com";
   lit.Text = "If you need help... contact <a onclick=\"javascript:void(window.open('" + myURL + "'\";>Help Link</a>)";
```

Then add the literal control to your page.  I tried to do a onclick event as you have in your code, but a href would work a lot easier.

Comment: Yes I did it with the HREF and it worked just fine:
 lit.Text = If you need help... contact <a target=\"_blank\" href= "+ myURL+ ">Help Link</a>";
                cell1.Controls.Add(lit);